# Can I REUSE the Dialogflow agent used in a Google Action for commercial purposes?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to implement and publish my first Google Action. The application will guide you in choosing a particular product according to the user's answers. The action will have Dialogflow as a backend. is it allowed using the same DialogFlow agent (or a clone of this) to drive an e-commerce support chat according to Google policies?
I tried to search for information with no result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can, but you should read the [terms of service](https://dialogflow.com/terms) to have an official answer.